# Add titles as H1 in accessible pdf using iText 7 and C#

Tags: c#, itext7, accessible

In `iText5`, we can use chapter and section to add titles and bookmarks.
Then title will displayed as `H1` tag in accessible PDF.
How I can do this in `iText7`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In iText7, you'd do it like this:

```
@Test
public void run() throws IOException {

    File outputFile = getOutputFile();

    PdfDocument pdfDocument = new PdfDocument(new PdfWriter(outputFile));
    pdfDocument.setTagged();

    Document layoutDocument = new Document(pdfDocument);

    Paragraph para = new Paragraph("The Raven")
                        .setFontColor(new DeviceRgb(8, 73, 117))
                        .setFontSize(20f);
                        para.getAccessibilityProperties().setRole(StandardRoles.H1);
    layoutDocument.add(para);

    layoutDocument.add(new Paragraph("Once upon a midnight dreary\nWhile I pondered weak and weary\nOver many a quaint and curious volume\nOf forgotten lore"));

    pdfDocument.close();

    Desktop.getDesktop().open(outputFile);
}
```

Checking the tags with Adobe Reader verifies the correct tagging has been applied.

[image]